# Choose default music player to play / pause music on hands-free button press

Tags: music, default-applications, hands-free

I like the feature to use button on the hands-free (headset) to play / pause music. I have a bunch of music players installed on my phone: Apollo, Sony Walkman, Play Music, etc. When I use the hands-free button to play music, every time it plays music from any one of the players. Is there any way to set a default player to play music on the hands-free button press?

Say for example, I want only Sony Walkman to play music when I press button on the hands-free instead of launching any other player randomly.

Can this be done?

I have a Sony Xperia Neo V (code name: Haida) running CyanogenMod 9. Android version 4.0.4.

Answer (score 2):

You could check the playstore for headset control apps. Having a Philips headset, [Philips Headset](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.philips.cl.headset) works perfectly for me -- and lets me define which player app to launch as soon as the headset is connected, plus gives me a bunch of control options for the headset's single button (e.c. click for play/pause or take call, long-press to increase volume, click twice to skip a title or reject a call, and more).

There are many more similar apps available. Quite famous examples include e.g. [JAYS Headset Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.jays.headsetcontrol) (which did not work that well with my Philips headset -- but that may be caused by the headset itself), and [Headset Button Controller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kober.headsetbutton). Simply [search the playstore for "headset control"](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=headset+control&c=apps) for more options.

Answer (score 0):

Most of popular music players have settings to override default behavior of hands free buttons.

Check your Sony walkman have that settings?

Comment: Nope. None of the music apps I have have this setting. And Sony Walkman was just an example. I might wanna set Play Music as default.

Comment: To check it I installed the playerpro music player and there is a headset settings in settings menu. It worked very well.

Comment: I don't know what app are you talking about. (Not willing to switch to any other music player now..) But I have used some players which had a setting to enable / disable hands-free music control. However, this did NOT assure that only that app was controlled... And that's what my question is.