# how do I make the radio start automatically when I plug in my headset?

Tags: headphones, fm-radio, sony-xperia

On my old phone, the radio would automatically turn on when I plugged in my headset. I can't seem to get it to do the same on my new phone?

I have a Sony Xperia go, running jelly bean.

Comment: Mostly out of curiosity, but there's a chance it could help get an answer: What was your old phone?

Comment: Well, let me trigger a search for answers here: [headset control](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=headset+control+user%3Ame) is the keyword. Admitted, not that obvious from the answers found (see e.g. [this one](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/38700/16575)) – but most of those apps [allow to define what app shall be started](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/34876/16575) on the headset-plugged-in event.

Comment: My old was an Xperia s, I think.

Answer (score 1):

[Plug in launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.launcher.plugin) is a free app that lets you launch any app once you plug-in your headset.

Answer (score 1):

As I've already pointed out in a comment on the question, there are plenty of [headset control](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=headset+control+user%3Ame) answers (see e.g. [this one](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/38700/16575)). Those app give you some added control using your headset, so they [allow to define what app shall be started](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/34876/16575) when the headset is plugged in, and using the single headset button they let you perform a multitude of actions like volume control, start/stop, skip, pick up/reject call, and more.

A different approach could make use of our "ultimate automation tool" [Tasker](http://www.appbrain.com/app/tasker/net.dinglisch.android.taskerm), which also can supervise the headset plug. This would give you even greater control over the conditions. So you could e.g. have a different app started at home than at work. Here you could use *State → Headset plugged* as condition (and optionally, ad described, location, time, whether power is connected, the device docked...), and then *Load App* as action. You could even have set the volumes to your likeness before, and let *Tasker* send an SMS to everybody to not to disturb you while enjoying your music ;)

[image: Tasker Actions] [image: Tasker Profiles]
<sup>Available *Tasker* actions and example profiles (source: Google Play; click for larger images)</sup>

Funny thing is: as the second picture shows, your case is even used for the example pictures on Google Play (Headset Plugged → Start Music)...